# converting char to integer in a vector

Tags: r

I am reading data from an excel file. Data in the excel file is like this:

```
45,25,12,36,14
```

with this code:

```
wb <- loadWorkbook("C:\\users\\bla\\bla\\Muster.xls")
dat <-readWorksheet(wb, sheet=getSheets(wb)[1], startRow=2, endRow=35, startCol=1, endCol=1,header=FALSE)
datalist<-dat[,1]
datalist
```

I have this output

```
[1]   "45,25,12,36,14"
[2]   "33,52,26,37,40"
...
```

I would like to do mathematic operation with these outputs like this:

```
k<-datalist[1]-datalist[2]
```

but I get an error, becuase they are in `char` format. my question is now:

How can I convert these char to a real integer in a vector? and then do mathematic operation on them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split the string into separate numbers (`strsplit`) and convert them into numerics which will  (`as.numeric`). `x` is `datalist` in your case.

```
x <- c("45,25,12,36,14", "33,52,26,37,40")
l <- strsplit(x, ",")
d <- sapply(l, as.numeric)
d

      [,1] [,2]
[1,]   45   33
[2,]   25   52
[3,]   12   26
[4,]   36   37
[5,]   14   40
```

Now you have a matrix containing the values in each column. The rest is straightforward,

```
d[, 1] - d[, 2]

[1]  12 -27 -14  -1 -26
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum, if each column contains a single figure then you can use the `ColTypes` argument to `readWorksheet` of the `XLConnect` library (which is what you are using in the above snippet) to ensure that the data you read is interpreted appropriately. If you had one column with a date followed by four holding numerics, you would do something like this, for example:

```
my.cols <- c("Date",
          rep("numeric",4))

wb = loadWorkbook(my.file)
tn <- readWorksheet(wb, my.sheet, colTypes = my.cols)
```